# rsyslog - stack property based filters (or Rainer solution)

Tags: rsyslog

I need the following filter in rsyslog.  My syntax is incorrect and it generates an error in the rsyslog logfile:

```
:programname, isequal, "program1" &
:msg, contains, "an expression" /dev/null
&~
```

Error is:

```
the last error occured in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, line 18:":programname, isequal, "program1" &"
```

I'd appreciate if someone could suggest the correct syntax for this property filter, or alternatively the correct RainerScript syntax to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer with some help from Rainer Gerhards:

```
if $programname == 'program1' and $msg contains 'an expression' then /dev/null
& stop
```

Note that for older versions of rsyslog (like V5 that Ubuntu provided with their V13 'Saucy'),  you must use single quotes around the attributes.  Double quotes work in late mode rsyslog versions like rsyslog V7

Comment: Why `... then /dev/null & stop` and not just `... then stop` ?